# converting iterator to pointer: really (&*it)?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

**note** *edited to address the reason for closing*

I need to obtain a pointer to an object for which I have an iterator. This is required whenever one has an iterator but needs to call a function (which may be third party) taking a pointer.

Is the ugly `(&*it)` (or even `it.operator->()`) really the standard idiom? Why is there no `ptr(iterator)` like

```
template<typename It>
inline auto ptr(It const&it) -> decltype(std::addressof(*it))
{
  return std::addressof(*it);
}
```

arguments supporting this:

1. It is descriptive and hence clearer (though this is indeed opinion-based).
2. It is safer: consider a type for which the `operator&` is overloaded
3. It avoids confusion with operator preference: consider
   `&*it->member();` (are you 100% sure what this does? it's not what you want ...)

Comment: Because it isn't needed?

Comment: What's wronig with `&*`? Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. If you stare at it long enough, even C++ becomes pretty ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Just search in any C++ code for the `&(it*)` idiom

Comment: @Walter: Is your point (no pun intended) that it's hard to search for?  That's true of lots of C++ constructs.

Comment: IM(Not So)HO, the issue is with the overloading of the `*` operator. 99% of the time you use it to dereference a pointer, and here you use it in an object to get a reference to a compeletely different object.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth He thought you meant that people don't need that functionality. But you simply meant that since there is a way to do it, you don't need another way.

Comment: Not every combination of operation needs its own shortcut (especially when the shortcut is longer than the construct it replaces). `&*it` is not terribly unintuitive either: I read it as "address of what the iterator refers to".

Comment: @ooga: Ah yes, now I see what Walter meant in his comment.

Comment: @delnan The problem with `&*it` is that of operator preference. Many programmers are not 100% sure about operator preference and when using `&*it` in some context, it's not clear (to them) how this will work out. With `ptr(it)` this cannot happen.

Comment: @Walter Then these people don't understand what operator precedence is *about*. Operator precedence has absolutely no bearing. The only way that can possibly be parsed is `&(*it)`, because `(&*)it` makes no sense at all. Plus, everything I said in the above comment holds just as well for the explicitly parenthesized form.

Comment: @delnan I think you may have missed *in some context* in my previous comment. Consider the context `&*it->member()`. I bet that to many it's not obvious what that does. (note that your original comment has no brackets around `&*it`).

Comment: @Walter Yes, that makes more sense. The brackets are actually necessary though, you (almost always) get a pretty nasty error if you omit them because `->` has precedence over `*`.

Comment: Mostly because if you're obtaining a pointer to an iteratee, you're probably doing something wrong. Either use pointers or iterators. Try not to use both. The other reason is that you can always make this function yourself if you need to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you are calling some function taking const_pointer but only have an iterator, what else can you do?

Comment: @Walter: Use a better function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *lol* This may not be an option in the real world.

Comment: @Walter: Enter a better real world.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried that, but for some reason ended up on SO.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function if you don't like the weird syntax:

```
std::address_of(*it);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think that some iterators (for example in vector or array) can be actualy implemented simply as pointers. Then any methods are not possible and this syntax `&*it` will work universal.

And by the way if you want `ptr(iterator)`, you can define something like this

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline T1* ptr(T2 it) {
    return &*it;
}
```

or more "hacky" way

```
#define ptr(x) (&*x)
```

Comment: *any methods are not possible* **nope**. you can have a free-standing `ptr(anything)` which checks (as compile time) that you actually do get a pointer.

Comment: ptr(anything) is not method, it's a function, i was saying that if an iterator is a pointer (non-class basic type), then you can't have methods

Comment: both of your functions/definitions are either useless or dangerous.

Comment: without any exact reasons, issue specifications or correction, your comment is useless

Comment: Your inline function is useless, because it requires the user to provide the type `T1` (since this cannot be derived by the compiler), i.e. must be called like `ptr<a_complicated_type_that_may_not_even_be_known>(it)`. Both (function and macro) may actually not return a pointer. The macro pollutes the glocal namespace, which is dangerous as otherwise valid code may become invalid or (worse) obtain different run-time behaviour. Never ever use macros like that.

Comment: Are you that retaliating downvoter?

Comment: me? i think i can't downvote yet, i registered 2 days ago